# Odoo11. Enviar vista a Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, odoo

Actualmente trabajo con Odoo 11.

Tengo el siguiente caso:

Supongamos que estamos en la vista de Contactos, cualquier usuario puede configurar dicha vista a su manera, agregar filtro, agrupar, y de esta manera crea una vista personalizada de la información que quiere ver.

Deseo crear un código, que me lleve esa vista personalizada a un archivo de Excel. Hasta ahora se me ocurre, agregar un botón en el menú de Acciones (el que se activa cuando seleccionas un elemento en la vista de lista) y que lleve un código javascript para barrer la tabla y de allí crear el excel.

La razón de querer resolverlo de esa manera es que cada usuario tiene su propia vista en contactos, productos, pedidos, etc. Esto seria como una solución genérica.

No se si esto sea posible en Odoo 11, o si hay una mejor manera de resolver esto.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya vistes este módulo?, creo que es lo que buscas https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_export_view/

Comment: Hola, gracias, si eso es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: ¿Como puedo marcar la pregunta como respondida con el mensaje de: Didierh?